# Cannot get mongodb $group to work with an objectID and $match

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

```
WhiskeySchema.statics.count = function (data){
    var distillerIds = data.map(function (a) {
        return a.distiller._id;
    });
    return Whiskey
        .aggregate([
            { $group: {
                // Group by fields to match on distiller
                _id: { distiller: '$distiller'},
                // Count number of matching whiskeys for the group
                count: { $sum:  1 }
            }},
                {
                    $match: {
                        distiller : {
                            $in: distillerIds
                        }
                    }
                }
    ])
    .execAsync()
    .then(function(countedData){
        console.log('counted data :', countedData)
        return countedData;
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log('whiskey count err : ', err);
    })
};
```

distiller / $distiller is a mongo ObjectID. A reference.

I want to find by specific Ids, as I'm doing in the match.

Then, of those matched results, I want to group them when the distiller Id is the same within whiskey, and count them. (trying to count the total number of whiskeys for each distiller).

The match works as expected, but when I include the group and count -- I keep getting an empty array returned for countedData.

```
counted data : []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The group part of your aggregation is not correct, change it to:

```
.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        distiller : {
            $in: distillerIds
        }
    }
}
{ $group: {
    // Group by fields to match on distiller
    _id: '$distiller',
    // Count number of matching whiskeys for the group
    count: { $sum:  1 }
}}
```

I also moved the match, it's best to do the match in the first pipeline stage so it uses the indexes present on the collection. When further in the pipeline no index can be used.